# Unexpected uninstalling virtualbox-5.1 when installing PHP5

Tags: virtualbox, php

System Ubuntu 14.04   64 bits

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

I got the line

`Uninstalling virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.26-117224~Ubuntu~trusty)`

After all, the installation is successful, but unexpected virtualbox uninstallation was done.

In the other hand, when I run [virtualbox-.1_5.1.26-117224~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.26/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.26-117224~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb)
with software center, virtualbox is successfully installed, but PHP5 is unexpectedly uninstalled.

why?

how can I manage to install both programs, php5 and virtualbox.

Thank you for your directions.

Comment: Look at that virtualbox file it's for a 32bit system try down loading the 64bit version